# Need turn by turn navigation (voice enabled) like google maps for phonegap cordova HTML5 mobile app

Tags: ios, html, google-maps, cordova

Does Google allow using its Maps API to get turn by turn navigation from another app? what are some other maps framework to be considered to get this functionality? Some example would really help.

Or will the only option be to call Google Maps/Apple Maps app from my app?

Comment: [*No Navigation, Autonomous Vehicle Control, or Enterprise Applications*](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_2)

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle So is it okay to display user his current location using Google Maps and then for turn by turn navigation call the google maps from within the app by passing the coordinates